# How to use a loop inside message.react() inside async function discord.js

Tags: node.js, loops, async-await, discord.js

I am making a message that allows the user to target another user via a Discord reaction for a game I'm making compatible with Discord. I am trying to make this work for any number of players without specifying each possible amount of players. I have been using a loop to try and make this work. I just want the bot to add a reaction of 1, 2 and 3 as options for a game that has 3 total players (or users) and display the correct 1, 2 or 3 emoji I have specified in reaction_numbers below. (Those emoji's are just blue squares with the number in them that I know work with Discord reactions)

I get an error of `(node:10988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji`

```
var reaction_numbers = ["\u0030\u20E3","\u0031\u20E3","\u0032\u20E3","\u0033\u20E3","\u0034\u20E3","\u0035\u20E3", "\u0036\u20E3","\u0037\u20E3","\u0038\u20E3","\u0039\u20E3"]

 var PlayerListMessage = [] <<< Gets list of players and arranges them
            for (let i = 0; i < playerUserArray.length; i++) {
                PlayerListMessage.push(`${i+1}: ${playerUserArray[i]}\n`)    
            }



  async function QuestionPlayerToTarget(){

let msg = await message.author.send(`Which player activated the card you would like to negate?\n${PlayerListMessage.join("")}\nPlease select only one player.`)
       for (var i of playerUserArray){
           await msg.react(reaction_numbers[i+(1)]) <<< Error happens here.
           }


const filter = (reaction, user) => {
return [reaction_numbers[1], reaction_numbers[2], reaction_numbers[3], reaction_numbers[4], reaction_numbers[5], reaction_numbers[6]].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
                    };

  const reply = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
                        .catch(console.error);

     const targetPlayer = reply.first()
     return targetPlayer
                }



     var targetPlayer = await QuestionPlayerToTarget()
     console.log(targetPlayer)
```

Any ideas on how to make this loop add reactions for the exact number of players in the game? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't too far off in my attempts. I ended up changing the loop type from a "for of" loop to a standard for loop and it worked as expected. Code changes as follows.

```
for (let i = 1; i < playerUserArray.length; i++) {
await msg.react(reaction_numbers[i])
}

var reaction_numbers = ["\u0031\u20E3","\u0032\u20E3","\u0033\u20E3","\u0034\u20E3","\u0035\u20E3", "\u0036\u20E3","\u0037\u20E3","\u0038\u20E3","\u0039\u20E3", "\u0030\u20E3"]
```

I also took the first value of reaction_numbers and put it at the end of the list in order to make index value 0 = emoji of the number 1 with the blue square.

Comment: In the `for...of` loop, `i` was the *element* of the array. Here, `i` is the step / *index*.

Answer (score 0):

Next time please comment with `#` not `<<<`

---

As the error says: `Emoji must be a string or Emoji/ReactionEmoji` > string or emoji.

### How to use `msg.react()`

So you can either use `msg.react("emoji")` or `msg.react(msg.guild.emojis.get("emojiid"))`.

The first option is for already existing emojis, like numbers in blue squares.
So in Discord you can put a `\` before you post an emoji and you are getting this emoji as string.

The second option is for guild-emojis, emojis, which are only available in this guild.

### In your Case

use http://getemoji.com/ and search for "one" and you'll get `1️⃣`. You can use this symbol for `msg.react("1️⃣")`.
So just put this in the list `reaction_numbers` and so on...

Comment: I know how to use emojis in this way. I've used them a ton in my discord bot so far. As my question stated, I need to know how to use a LOOP with the msg.react(), because the way I think it would work doesn't work.... I need to make it work in a way that will loop through and react with a number for each player in the game (aka the amount of players in the playerUserArray).